# Is openpyxl iter_rows() skipping last row?

Tags: python, openpyxl, import-from-excel

I have difficulties using openpyx iter_rows.

The source excel has rows in the first column (A) :

- header
- 1st data row
- ...
- 32nd data row

The code:

```
start, stop = 0, 1000    
for row_index, row in enumerate(source_ws.iter_rows()):
    if start < row_index < stop:                
       # something meaning here
```

does not visit the last 32nd data row but breaks out at 31st row.
There are no empty lines between the rows.

I made an evil hack to circumvent this behaviour, but it's not a long lasting option.

Environment:

- Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23)
- jdcal==1.0
- openpyxl==2.1.5

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Really need a file to say but it's possible the file has incorrect "dimensions".

Comment: This works:

`for row_index, row in enumerate(source_ws.iter_rows(), start=1):
         # something meaning here
`

So openpyxl works ok. I knew I did it wrong

Comment: If depends what you're wanting to do. If you're expecting row_index to represent a row in the sheet then it will need to start at 1; Python uses 0-based indexing, Excel 1-based.

Comment: That's correct. I had the all time classic #2, off-by-one in my loop. Thank you Charlie for your comments and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws.iter_rows()` will loop through all rows unless you tell it otherwise. If you want to limit it then you can use `ws.get_squared_range(1, 1, 32, ws.max_column)` (First 32 rows).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'less than or equal' operator for row index stop condition:

```
start, stop = 0, 1000    
for row_index, row in enumerate(source_ws.iter_rows()):
    if start < row_index <= stop:                
       # something meaning here
```

or you can use list comprehension and 'row' number attribute to drop enumerate. Please note that iter_rows() is counting rows from 1 not 0.

```
    start, stop = 1, 1000    
    for row in [row for row in source_ws.iter_rows() if start < row[0].row <= stop]:
        #do something
```